# How to make an action after touching two buttons?

Tags: java, android

I have 9 buttons on an activity, and want to handle clicking on two buttons -any of them- (respectively not spontaneously), is there any way to do that?

Comment: Two clicklistener, one timer, one flag

Comment: Do you mean when they press button A and then button B, something should happen? But if they press any other combination of buttons it won't?

Comment: @BretC No, any two buttons.

Comment: @MuratK. could you explain in details because I am still rookie :) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you create your own click listener as so...

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
     private Button firstButton;

     public void onClick(View v) {
         if(firstButton == null) {
             firstButton = (Button) v;
         } else {
             twoButtonsWereClicked(firstButton, (Button) v);
             firstButton = null;
         }
     }
};
```

...and implement the method `twoButtonsWereClicked` to do what you want it to do, then add this listener to the buttons you want this to happen for.

The `twoButtonsWereClicked` method can pretty much do anything you want.

Hope this helps

Comment: @MohammadAbubeih This is the method you need to write which actually does what you want when two buttons are clicked

Comment: What would I write inside it ??

Comment: uhhhh, whatever you want to happen when two buttons are pressed... remove that line and put whatever you want there (but its cleaner to write that code as a separate method).